# Modify SwiftUI @State from a regular class function using Bindings

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui

I am trying to crate a regular class function that takes an optional `Binding<Bool>` as a parameter. The idea is that the function will modify the boolean to disable/enable a SwitUI `View` without the need for callback blocks.

The problem is that I can't find the proper way to modify the boolean from within the function.

```
func executeTask(inProgress: Binding<Bool>? = nil)
{
    inProgress = true // Error
    // ...
    inProgress = false // Error
}
```

The error:

> Cannot assign to value: 'inProgress' is a 'let' constant

I also tried to mimic SwiftUI behavior by creating a `@Binding var inProgress: Bool` in the class, assign it, and then modify it with no luck.

Also I would be OK with a non-optional 'inProgress' if that helps, but so far it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the `Binding`'s value, you should assign the new value to its `wrappedValue` property.

try this:

```
func executeTask(inProgress: Binding<Bool>? = nil)
{
    inProgress?.wrappedValue = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Binding` is a special wrapper, which gives access to references stored value via `.wrappedValue`

Here is fixed variant (tested with Xcode 12)

```
func executeTask(inProgress: Binding<Bool>? = nil) {
    // optional chain
    inProgress?.wrappedValue = true
}
```